# CSS Make Horizontal List Contents Fill Height

Tags: css, html-lists, fill

http://jsfiddle.net/K4ZGg/
**Update** this is the right jsfiddle link

My JsFiddle has my attempt so far. I really want to make the items in the menu fill the height of the menu, and be centered in it's list item.

Please help. (I apologize for the simplicity of the question, I promise I've been trying to figure this out for a while)

**HTML**

```
<header id="navmenu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>Welcome <span id="firstName"></span></label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" onclick="return false;">Option One</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" onclick="return false;">Option Two</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

**Bare CSS (Full is on JsFiddle Link)**

```
#navmenu {
    background-color: rgba(250, 250, 210, 1);
    text-align:right;
    height:42px;
    width:100%
}
#navmenu ul {
    height:42px;
}
#navmenu ul li {
    display:inline;
    padding: 0 8px;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: solid 1px black;
}
#navmenu ul li:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line-height is the way to go. Just set the list items line height to the same height of the container (the ul in this case)

```
#navmenu ul li {
display:inline;
padding: 0 8px;
height: 100%;
border-right: solid 1px black;
    line-height: 42px;
}
```

If you want the black lines to get to border of the ul just set the list items to inline block:

```
#navmenu ul li {
display:inline-block;
padding: 0 8px;
height: 100%;
border-right: solid 1px black;
    line-height: 42px;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/K4ZGg/1/

**EDIT**: As the OP requested that the link would be selectable for the entire height:

```
#navmenu ul li a{
   line-height: 42px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

We need to make the entire anchor span the whole height of the list item. Same trick as above: line height to span the full height.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/K4ZGg/5/

Comment: Thank you for the explicit css block. and the second one for line height

Comment: Though I may have spoken too soon. The link is only selectable when clicking on the text. I want the link to span the entire height

Comment: This is great, but what about responsive layouts? What if I need it to be 100% height?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
#navmenu {
    background-color: rgba(250, 250, 210, 1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    text-align:right;
    height:42px;
    width:100%
}
#navmenu ul {
    -webkit-margin-before: 0em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0em;
    padding: 0 12px;
    height:42px;
  float: right;
}
#navmenu ul li {
    **display:block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 42px;**

}
#navmenu ul li:first-child {
    **padding-right: 8px;**
}
#navmenu a {
    text-decoration:none;
  **border-left: solid 1px black;
  padding: 0 8px;**
}
```

Please view the [demo](http://codepen.io/airen/pen/uliJH).

Comment: I appreciate the answer however this isn't 100% correct. In you example the link is only selectable on it's text.